# Invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference on slice

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-endpoints

Why does greets give me `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` when running?

```
type Response struct {
  Message string `json:"message"`
}

type ResponseList struct {
  Items []*Response `json:"items"`
}

func (gs *GreetingService) List(r *http.Request, req *Request, resp *ResponseList) error {
  greets := make([]*Response,2,2)
  greets[0].Message="hello"
  greets[1].Message="goodbye"
  resp.Items = greets
  return nil
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't allocated the Response objects, just pointers. Pointers are inited to nil.

You could say `greets[0] := &Response{Message: "hello"}`. Or, perhaps better, start with an empty slice and `append` as many `*Response`s as you want:

```
greets := []*Response{} // or ResponseList{}
greets = append(greets, &Response{Message: "hello"})
greets = append(greets, &Response{Message: "goodbye"})
```

*Edit:* Note Anonymous's alternative: you can use a literal to set up the whole structure if you know the number of `Response`s, as in `resp.Items = {{Message: "hello"}}`. Works even though Response is a pointer, and works without an explicit type name on each `Response`. Very cool.

Answer (score 2):

The support for slice and struct literals in Go can help you avoid the boilerplate as well as get your code right.

Here's how to write your `List` method using a slice literal.

```
func (gs *GreetingService) List(r *http.Request, req *Request, resp *ResponseList) error {
    resp.Items = []*Response{
        {Message: "hello"},
        {Message: "goodbye"},
    }
    return nil
}
```